# LocalStorage and Xss

Tags: xss, security, local-storage

Can localstorage value of a site be overwritten by xss(cross-site-scripting)? As far as I have verified in chrome and firefox, the localstorage value of a site is not accessible by a different site. Can anyone tell me whether the localstorage value can be read/write from a different domain in the browser by xss ?

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays many websites, add third-party js libraries for Analytic, A/B testing, Marketing tools, Heat maps and ... You may be sure about your codes but if one of these scripts, is vulnerable then you should expect XSS attack easily and in this case, It can grab your localStorage. Don't use local storage for session identifiers or sensitive tokens. Stick with cookies and use the `HTTPOnly` and Secure flags. To prevent CSRF attacks on Cookies, almost all requests include one or both of: `Origin` Header and `Referer` Header. CSRF can be partially prevented by checking the HTTP Referer and Origin header from your API. CSRF attacks will have Referer and Origin headers that are unrelated to your application.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript coming from reflected XSS or similar can do whatever normal JS can do on the domain where the XSS exists. So if example.com has stored things in localStorage and example.com also has an XSS flaw, then that XSS vuln can be used to extract or overwrite users data in localStorage. You could even use a reflected XSS, which exploits a DOM-based XSS using data from localStorage, meaning a client side persistent XSS.

Answer (score 0):

Web storage (local and session) follow [single origin policy](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#security-storage). So it XSS access to web storage is not possible.